# Getting Segmentation violation signal error on copying vector elements?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl, c++17

I have the following code for doing a http post request. I am getting the response in
`const std::vector<json> value` ...The below code works correctly

```
Ttran<std::vector<Lar>> get() const {
 
  const std::vector<json> value = res["value"];
  std::vector<Lar> account;
  for (const json &account : value) {
    account.push_back(account);
  }
  return {res["context"], accounts};
}
```

To improve the appending of elements into `accounts` vector..I am trying to use std::copy()
But getting this error: FATAL ERROR: test case CRASHED: SIGSEGV - Segmentation violation signal

I am trying this way:

```
Ttran<std::vector<Lar>> get() const {

  const std::vector<json> value = res["value"];
  std::vector<Lar> accounts;
  std::copy(value.begin(), value.end(), accounts.begin());
  return {res["context"], accounts};
}
```

What I am doing wrong ?

Comment: `std::vector<Largest> accounts_list { value.begin(), value.end() };` would be preferable to both alternatives, even if you make the second approach work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reserve` does not `resize` the vector, it just pre-allocates the space so `push_back`s are cheap and never invalidate any iterators but they are still required.

`std::copy` assumes (like most `<algorithm>`s) the output iterators are valid, i.e. point to existing location. In this case they do not.

What you need is `std::back_inserter` which will call `push_back` for you:

```
accounts_list.reserve(value.size()); // Optional optimization
std::copy(value.begin(), value.end(), std::back_inserter(accounts_list));
```

I am not actually sure whether this is the cause since you did not provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), I would expect some iterator assertion, not segfault since the memory should have been allocated. Maybe some empty `std::vector` optimization is at play.

Comment: Directly using the `std::vector` constructor for this would be even better than using multiple `push_back` calls...